# Is it possible to create a python executable (py2xe) that contains a celery worker task?

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery, py2exe

Is it possible to create a python executable (py2xe) that contains a celery worker task ?
I am getting the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tasks.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "celery\five.pyc", line 307, in __getattr__
  File "celery\app\__init__.pyc", line 22, in <module>
  File "celery\app\base.pyc", line 48, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name builtins
```

Comment: We can't import builtins (there's no such module). You can correct it using `import __builtin__` on Python 2.7

Comment: yes I manage to overcome this problem by adding 'packages' : ['matplotlib', 'celery'], in my setup.py . Now the executable can be executed ok , but does nothing simply returns to the command prompt again.